# Streamlit bug out of nowhere while I can still run it successfully in localhost

Tags: python, pandas, types, streamlit

[My app](https://junegroceryshopping.streamlit.app/) was working perfectly fine months ago and still works fine when I host it locally but now I see this bug I can't solve.Has anyone encountered this and have a fix for it? To be specific, the error occurs when I run a couple of comma separated hellofresh URLs as provided in the instructions of the app:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
Traceback:
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 332, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/mount/src/recipescraper/streamlit.py", line 269, in <module>
    df_download = create_df(recs)
File "/mount/src/recipescraper/streamlit.py", line 213, in create_df
    res['Total'] = res.drop(['Ingredients', 'Measurement'], axis=1).sum(axis=1)
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 11315, in sum
    result = super().sum(axis, skipna, numeric_only, min_count, **kwargs)
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 12055, in sum
    return self._min_count_stat_function(
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 12038, in _min_count_stat_function
    return self._reduce(
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 11207, in _reduce
    res = df._mgr.reduce(blk_func)
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1459, in reduce
    nbs = blk.reduce(func)
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 377, in reduce
    result = func(self.values)
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 11139, in blk_func
    return op(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py", line 85, in _f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py", line 404, in new_func
    result = func(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, mask=mask, **kwargs)
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py", line 477, in newfunc
    return func(values, axis=axis, **kwargs)
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py", line 646, in nansum
    the_sum = values.sum(axis, dtype=dtype_sum)
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 49, in _sum
    return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I can't reproduce your problem on a similar configuration as your requirements.txt & python3.9, I think I understand the problem for your mysterious `TypeError`.

At the line 213, you're always dropping two object columns ("`Ingredients"` and `"Measurements"`) to [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) the remaining values according to the `axis=1` right after that. But you missed one important thing: Sometimes the `res` DataFrame can hold more objects (*strings in particular*) columns than these two or simply different ones (*like in the example below*) :

```
# Ingredient list
# https://www.hellofresh.nl/recipes/chicken-parmigiana-623c51bd7ed5c074f51bbb10
# https://www.hellofresh.nl/recipes/quiche-met-broccoli-en-oude-kaas-628665b01d..

         Category  chicken-parmigiana  quiche-met-broccoli-en-oude-kaas
    0  Vegetables                 0.0                             400.0
    1           0              1000.0                               0.0
    2           0                 0.0                               8.0
    3           0                 2.0                               0.0
    4           0                 0.0                               2.0

# In this case, the TypeError is triggered by the value "Vegetables"
```

You need to turn on `numeric_only` (`True` by default in older versions of pandas in [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)). So, I suppose that your host is running a newer version (than your local's) where this parameter is `False` by default. Anyways, to solve your problem for sure, you need to replace the line 213 :

```
res['Total'] = res.drop(['Ingredients', 'Measurement'], axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```

By this one :

```
res['Total'] = res.sum(axis=1, numeric_only=True)
```